# Visual C++ 2005 merged modules not installing

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, installshield-le, merge-module, visual-c++-2005

I've written a Crystal Report Viewer in VB .NET (VS 2013).

It works fine for the most part, but I found on certain PCs I was faced with the error:

> The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.CRPE threw and exception

So after a long trial and error (and an incredible degree of google searching) I found out CrystalReports for VB has a dependency with Visual C++ 2005 Redistribution.

So I got the merged modules and incorporated them with my installer. Only to find out that I need specific '8.0.50727.762' versions that came with the ATL Security Update. Not '8.0.50727.42' that I had. So I had to install Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2005 in order to get these new updated merged modules!

Only to find I'm faced with the same error.

The merged modules are as follows:

```
Visual C++ 8.0 OpenMP 
Visual C++ 8.0 MFC
Visual C++ 8.0 MFCLOC
Visual C++ 8.0 CRT
Visual C++ 8.0 ATL
SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4 (CRRuntime_12_0_16.msm)
```

(I also have the corresponding policy .MSM's)
After I run the installer and run the program, I get the error.

If I immediately install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package ATL Security Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=14431)

The program works fine.

Does anyone have any knowledge of getting these merged modules to install this VC++ redistribution?

Program, merged modules and reidstribution are all 32-bit X86.

I'm using VS 2013 with InstallShield LE. Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 version number is 8.0, and it looks like you are using 9.0

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake! They are version 8. Thanks